# JavaFX/Controlsfx - How to monitor item change in a PropertySheet?

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx, propertysheet

Is there a convenice way to monitor the propertysheet item status? Like textfield get focused, boolean status change, etc.

I've looked the javadoc,did't find one.

And there's an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/535/propertysheet-does-not-respond-to-javabean) here, but the solution seems to let the editor know the change of a property.

What I want is just in the opposite, monitor the editor.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PropertySheet:

```
/**
 * Sets a new editor factory used by the PropertySheet to determine which
 * {@link PropertyEditor} to use for a given {@link Item}.
 * @param factory 
 */
public final void setPropertyEditorFactory( Callback<Item, PropertyEditor<?>> factory ) {
    propertyEditorFactory.set( factory == null? new DefaultPropertyEditorFactory(): factory );
}
```

If you create a callback to a PropertyEditor you can add listeners to the editor.

For example:

```
    SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>> propertyEditorFactory = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "propertyEditor", new DefaultPropertyEditorFactory());
    projectSheet.setPropertyEditorFactory(getItemPropertyEditorCallback(propertyEditorFactory));



private Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>> getItemPropertyEditorCallback(SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<PropertySheet.Item, PropertyEditor<?>>> propertyEditorFactory) {
    return param -> {
        PropertyEditor<?> editor = propertyEditorFactory.get().call(param);

        //Add listeners to editor
        editor.getEditor().focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));

        return editor;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested the example code,but not working for me. I don't understand the PropertyItemBase, it can't be a PropertySheet.Item, right? Because there isn't a setEditor() method in its methods. So, what is it?      @bonfatti

Comment: I've meant to remove the itemBase part of the code before pasting it my comment, sorry about that. The PropertyItemBase is an implementation of the PropertySheet.Item containing a instance of the editor, plus getter and setter. I will edit my answer to remove the itemBase.